# Upload Web Font

Tags: marketing-cloud, upload, font

would it be able to upload a Web Font in ExactTarget? I only get the font as a otf-File.

If i try to upload i get a respone of "Invalid file type selected."

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload a font file into the Portfolio.

This is slightly out of date, but gives a good idea of acceptable file types: [Supported File Types](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/getting_started_with_portfolios/supported_file_types/)

If you want to use a webfont, you will need to use a CDN (e.g. [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)) via link or `@import` from an outside hosted location.

This is supported in a very few email clients. See this Campaign Monitor page for reference: [Using Webfonts in Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/)